# How to Retrieve XML Nodes from SQL Server using XQuery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am having this little puzzle to figure out and thought you could help me out.

So I have this kind of structure in my XML Field on SQL Server?

```
<negocio>
  <qualificado>N</qualificado>
  <local>BOVESPA</local>
  <natureza>V</natureza>
  <mercado>VIS</mercado>
  <prazo />
  <isin>BRPETRACNPR6</isin>
  <especificacao>PETROBRAS PN</especificacao>
  <observacao>D</observacao>
  <quantidade>500</quantidade>
  <precoajuste>20,91</precoajuste>
  <volume>10455</volume>
  <financeironegocio liquidoneg="10398,51">
    <cblc>
      <valoropera>10455</valoropera>
      <taxaliquidacaoneg>-2,09</taxaliquidacaoneg>
      <taxaregistroneg>0</taxaregistroneg>
    </cblc>
    <bolsa>
      <taxaprazoneg>0</taxaprazoneg>
      <taxaananeg>0</taxaananeg>
      <emolumentoneg>-0,52</emolumentoneg>
    </bolsa>
    <corretora>
      <corretagemneg>-52,63</corretagemneg>
      <intermediacaoneg>-1,82</intermediacaoneg>
    </corretora>
    <cliente>
      <issneg>2,63</issneg>
      <irrfoperacoesneg>0</irrfoperacoesneg>
      <irrfdtneg>1,25</irrfdtneg>
      <outrasdespesasneg>0</outrasdespesasneg>
    </cliente>
  </financeironegocio>
</negocio>
<negocio>
```

This structure repeats itself a lot of times and I need to get the information from each one of them. I know using .value queries like the one below can get me the first hit in the whole XML.

```
 select texto.value('(identificador/evento/negocio/financeironegocio/cliente/issneg)[5]','varchar(100)') from #tempxml
```

My question here is: How do I get the others? If I use [2],[3] I can get them but I don't know how much  nodes I will have in each file and I need to get all of them.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT
    issneg = XC.value('(issneg)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTableName
CROSS APPLY
    YourXmlColumnName.nodes('/negocio/financeironegocio/cliente') AS XT(XC)
```

Basically, this takes the XML elements that match that XPath expression (all `<cliente>` nodes in that structure) and creates a pseudo table in memory, called `XT`, with a single column `XC` of type `XML`. You can now query that pseudo table / column to grab out individual bits and pieces. And this will create a table with as many rows as there are `<cliente>` elements in your XML structure.